# updating multible rows values by adding them and subtracting one value and storing the remaining values in the rows using laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have three tables which are joined: Item, Inventory and Used Inventory.
[items table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRbNE.png)[Inventories table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Xpnm.png)[used inventories table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozK1R.png)
As you can see, I want to update Quantity of Inventory when used inventory is added.
because used inventory and inventory are both connected to Item table.
so the problem is when I try to update the quantity in Inventory Table by getting the Item id, I have to sum all the quantities of Item and then subtract the Used Quantity and update the rest in the Quantity of Inventory.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'item_id'=>'required',
        'project_id'=>'required',
        'quantity'=>'required',
    ]);

    $used_inventories = new UsedInventory();
    $used_inventories->item_id = $request->item_id;
    $used_inventories->project_id = $request->project_id;
    $used_inventories->quantity = $request->quantity;
    $used_inventories->reference = $request->reference;
    $used_inventories->description = $request->description;

    $item = Item::where('id','=',$request->item_id)->get();
    $used_quantity = $request->quantity;
    foreach ($item as $i){
        $updated_quantities = $i->inventories->pluck('quantity')->sum();

        $quantity_now = $updated_quantities - $used_quantity;

        if ($used_quantity > $updated_quantities)
        {
            return back()->with('warning','This Quantity is not available');
        }
        $inventory_update = DB::table('inventories')
            ->where('item_id',$request->item_id)
            ->update(['quantity'=>$quantity_now]);
        $used_inventories->save();
    }

    return back()->with('save_success','Used Inventory');

}
```

Comment: Can you add more information and explicitly state your question? Because for people not ingrained in your project, it's not obvious what expected behavior should be without digging through your code.

Comment: item,inventory and used_inventory are the three tables,inventory and used_inventory both connected to the item. I want to store quantity of items in the inventory table. when this quantity is used, i want to subtract that quantity from the used quantity and store it in the used_inventory table.

Comment: So when subtracting used_inventory quantity quantity from inventory quantity,I have to update it,So the item may have many inventory Quantities, For example Item 'Y' may have quantity of '10', again it may have '20' in the inventory table,So if used_quantity of Item 'Y' is equal to '15', I have to subtract it from the Accregate of '10+20',because the item has both these quantites. and as you can understand, these two values are stored in different rows. so the problem is when I try to update the rows it will update all, I mean both '10'and '15' will be subtract '20'.

Comment: but what I want is to Sum and the subtract and update for example (10+15)-20 = 5, so the item will have 5 quantities in one of the rows.

Comment: Uh, it's still not very clear, but edit the question so that this information is there. Again - if I understand your problem correctly - if you need the used_quantity subtracted from the aggregated quantities in all inventories - assuming there are multiple inventories per item - you may have to enumerate and loop over each inventory and - for that item - subtract units until all 'used_quantity' elements are deducted.